# Sequential Criterion for the absence of Uniform Continuityy

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I am reading Abbott's Understanding Analysis wherein the sequential criterion for the absence of uniform continuity is given as follows:

A function $f : A \to\mathbb R$ fails to be uniformly continuous on $A$ if and only if there exists a particular $\epsilon_0 > 0$ and two sequences ($x_n$) and ($y_n$) in A satisfying $|x_n − y_n| \to 0$ but $|f(x_n) − f(y_n)| \ge \epsilon_0$.

I am not able to understand this completely. When I look at it as a negation of the definition of uniform continuity, it seems to be okay to my understanding but when I consider $f$ to be only continuous, I don't understand how to comprehend it.

So if $f$ is continuous on $A$ then for every $\epsilon$ nbd of $f(x)$, there exists a $\delta$ nbd of $x$ such that whenever $|x - y| < \delta$, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. Since $f$ is only continuous, the criterion above is valid here which says that there does exist an $\epsilon_0$ for which no $\delta$ will work.

Doesn't this contradict the definition of continuity which say that for every possible $\epsilon$, we can find a $\delta$?

Also as an exercise, I have to prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous and $A$ is bounded then $f(A)$ is bounded.

I think I will have to use the criterion mentioned above to prove this. By considering a convergent subsequence in $A$, since $A$ is bounded and then by assuming that $f(A)$ is unbounded I may arrive at a contradiction that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

I am hesitant to use the criterion in the proof because clearly, I don't understand it completely or maybe, not at all.

Please help me understand the criterion. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For the second part. Let $f(A)$ be unbounded. Then $\exists $ a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ such that $|f(x_n)| \gt n$ . Since $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, there is a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$. Now since uniformly continous functions maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy what can you say about $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ ?

Comment: I can say that {f(xn)} being Cauchy, should be bounded but according to the assumption it is not. Hence, a contradiction. Correct?

Comment: If you meant $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ , then yes, you are correct.

Comment: Of course, yes. Sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind uniform convergence is that there is a single $\varepsilon$ which serves to control the rate of convergence.  In other words, if you have a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$ and a function $f$ such that $f(x_n)$ is uniformly convergent then there is some $\delta(\varepsilon)$ which depends on $\varepsilon$ so that $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x_n-x_m|<\delta$.  In particular, once you choose your $\varepsilon$ that specifies the values you can choose for $\delta$ and whenever you take points of the sequence that are that close together, the corresponding values of $f$ are no further apart than $\varepsilon$.

Now, take two (infinite) subsequences of $\{x_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$, say $\{y_{n_k}\}_{k\in {\mathbb N}}$ and $\{z_{n_k}\}_{k\in {\mathbb N}}$.  Since they are subsequences of a convergent sequence they must converge to the same point, i.e.

$$y_{n_k} \rightarrow x \quad \mbox{ and } \quad z_{n_k} \rightarrow x $$
which means that $|y_{n_k} - z_{n_k}| \rightarrow 0$.  Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, this means that there exists some $\delta(\varepsilon)$ which depends on $\varepsilon$ so that $|f(y_{n_k})-f(z_{n_k})|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|y_{n_k}-z_{n_k}|<\delta$.

So, if $f$ is **not** uniformly convergent, there must be some $\varepsilon_0$ such that $|f(y_{n_k})-f(z_{n_k})|>\varepsilon_0$ even though $|y_{n_k}-z_{n_k}|<\delta$, i.e. $|f(y_{n_k})-f(z_{n_k})|>\varepsilon_0$ as $|y_{n_k}-z_{n_k}| \rightarrow 0$.

We can generalise this to your definition by noting that if there are any two sequences with this property then $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous (because we can combine those two sequences into one, of which they are subsequences, and then the reasoning above holds).

I think the comment above should cover the second part for you quite adequately.